# How do I properly call methods in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I installed https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable gem. I tried various stuff authors showed in documentation via Rails console. However I do not understand how to call these methods in views.

```
def vote
    @post.liked_by current_user
end
```

This for example is my view. Delete and edit work well, however Vote does not. What is a proper way to do this?

```
<% if current_user?(post.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", post, method: :delete %>,
    <%= link_to "edit", edit_post_path(post)%>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to "vote", post, method: :vote if logged_in? %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add routes? Something like:

```
resources :answers do 
  member do 
    put "like", to: "answers#upvote"
    put "dislike", to: "answers#downvote"
  end
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= link_to "", like_answer_path(answer), method: :put, class: "glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" %>

<%= link_to "", dislike_answer_path(answer), method: :put, class: "glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" %>
```

Comment: I used this structure you suggested, but I get this error : 
NoMethodError in PostsController#index , what might be the issue?

Comment: I created thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020051/instance-variable-cant-be-assigned-via-private-method

Answer (score 1):

You need a route for voting in your `routes.rb`, then you build your link the same way your delete and edit links are built: method name, object name, path:

`vote_post_path(post)`

The `method` argument is not a controller method, it is an [html verb](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html)