# Instance variable can't be assigned via private method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I use this link:

```
<%= link_to "upvote", post_upvote_path(post), method: :put %>
```

I get error :

> undefined method `liked_by' for nil:NilClass
>   Which is caused because variable @post inside method upvote is not properly assigned.

```
  def upvote
    @post = current_post
    @post.liked_by current_user
    redirect_to @post
  end

private
    def current_post
      current_user.posts.find_by(id: params[:id])
    end
```

private method current_post works fine in other methods inside this controller. However, inside this method it doesn't. For example If I used:

```
  def upvote
    @post = Post.first
    @post.liked_by current_user
    redirect_to @post
  end
```

instead, it would work fine, except for the part it would upvote first post instead of the one where link is clicked. What is the right approach to this problem? How do I assign this variable properly to work for post where upvote link is clicked?

The `rake routes | grep posts` output:

[image]

I noticed that this method has /posts/:post_id ... while others use :id . That might be the issue, how do I change it?

Comment: Can you correct the question to mean what exactly your problem is?

Comment: The problem is error:  `undefined method liked_by' for nil:NilClass ` which is most likely caused because instance variable is not assigned properly.

Comment: Can you please run the following command in your terminal and then edit your question to include the output:  `rake routes | grep posts`

Comment: @LukeGriffiths Yeah sorry, today notifications are kinda delayed on Stackoverflow so I didn't notice this comment before. I updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where was the problem. In routes file I needed to nest member method like this:

```
  resources :posts do
    member do
      put 'upvote', to: 'posts#upvote'
    end
  end
```

And then change view to this:

```
  <%= link_to "upvote", upvote_post_path(post), method: :put %>
```

And this method in controller works just right:

```
  def upvote
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.liked_by current_user
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your link_to you're passing post...is it in the context of an @posts loop? What page are you on when the voting is being done?

Try this:

```
def upvote
  puts "params: #{params.inspect}"
  @post = Post.find(params[:id]) # if this isn't working check out that puts statement in the stack trace
  @post.liked_by current_user 
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

Comment: I would consider raising an error if params[:id] is blank: `raise 'Cant be blank' if params[:id].blank?`

Answer (score 0):

in your routes file there is

`post_upvote  /posts/:post_id/upvote` and not `post_upvote  /posts/:id/upvote`

so actually
when you pass post to post_upvote_path method like that `post_upvote_path( post)` 
 in your controller you want to do `params[:post_id]` and not `params[:id]` because of what you wrote in your routes file

```
def current_post
  current_user.posts.find_by(id: params[:post_id]) #post_upvote /posts/:post_id/upvote
end
```

Answer (score -1):

This:

```
<%= link_to "upvote", post_upvote_path(post), method: :put %>
```

Should become:

```
<%= link_to "upvote", post_upvote_path(@post), method: :put %>
```

Comment: Nope, didn't fix anything.

Comment: @Kunok what is the URL that is generated by post_upvote_path(post) and is the variable in your view post or @post?

Comment: /posts/173/upvote  *note that 173 is id which is different for each post

Comment: I see you are using the put method is that what you have specified in routes? Or is it a post? Also, why not just use Post.find(params[:id]) instead of current_user.posts.find_by(id: params[:id])?

Comment: Yes this is specified in routes and as I mentioned in question the problem is caused in variable declaration. If I change variable to be @post = Post.first, then the code is working just fine, except the fact that it will upvote first post instead of current.

Comment: Change your current_post method to: Post.find(params[:I'd]) and see if that works.

Comment: Nope, didn't change anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106398/discussion-between-dane-and-kunok).

Comment: puts the params hash out when you hit that url `puts params.inspect`